# List has no rows to assign error: Need null check

Tags: apex, soql, class, list

I have below piece of code where it throws **Error** List has no row to assign at below marked line.

**Code**

```
get
    {   terrid = [select UserId, TerritoryID from Userterritory where UserID=: UserInfo.getUserId()].TerritoryID;
        ParentTerr = [select Parentterritoryid,ID from territory where ID=: terrid].Parentterritoryid;
        List<territory> territoryList= [select Parentterritoryid,ID from territory where ID=: ParentTerr ];
            if(territoryList!=null && !territoryList.isEmpty()){
                 PterrId = territoryList.get(0).Parentterritoryid;
            }
        DM = [select UserId,territoryid from userterritory where territoryid =: ParentTerr ].UserId; // This line throws error
        RM = [select UserId,territoryid from userterritory where territoryid =: PTerrId ].UserId;
        UserEmail=[select email from user where id = :UserInfo.getUserId()].Email;

        UserTemp = [Select u.LastName, u.Id, u.FirstName, u.Email From User u limit 1];

        UserList = new List<SelectOption>();

        for(User temp : UserTemp)
        {
            UserList.add(new SelectOption(temp.Id, temp.Email));

        }
        return UserList;
    }
        set;
```

Comment: The line tries to assign an ID to 'PterrId' - which I assume is an ID variable. Essentially the error means that the query on that line is not returning any records.

Comment: Another point, the query 'select Parentterritoryid,ID from territory where ID=: ParentTerr' returns a List<territory> . So you cannot access the 'Parentterritoryid' of a list, you need to specify which element of the list and then access the 'Parentterritoryid'. Thanks

Comment: Can you please correct me my code? I am not getting why Id can't be assigned?

Comment: can you confirm the second query always returning valid values?

Comment: Might not be , so it needs a null check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try to use list.

Check if list is not empty then get the value and assign to variable.

```
 List<territory >   lstterritory = [select Id, Parentterritoryid
                                      from territory where ID=: ParentTerr ];
if(!lstterritory.isEmpty())
   PterrId  = lstterritory[0].Parentterritoryid;
```

I suggest do for all the Queries.

---

### Updates

```
List<Userterritory>  lstUserterritory = [select UserId, TerritoryID from Userterritory where UserID=: UserInfo.getUserId()];
if(!lstUserterritory.isEmpty()){
    terrid = lstUserterritory[0].TerritoryID;
}

List<territory> lstterritory = [select Parentterritoryid,ID from territory where ID=: terrid].Parentterritoryid;
if(!lstterritory.isEmpty()){
    ParentTerr = lstterritory[0].Parentterritoryid;
}

List<territory >   lstterritory = [select Id, Parentterritoryid
                                      from territory where ID=: ParentTerr ];
if(!lstterritory.isEmpty()){
   PterrId  = lstterritory[0].Parentterritoryid;
 }

List<userterritory> lstUserterritory =[select UserId,territoryid from userterritory where territoryid =: ParentTerr ];
if(!lstUserterritory.isEmpty()){
     DM = lstUserterritory[0].UserId;
}

List<userterritory> lstUserterritory1 =[select UserId,territoryid from userterritory where territoryid =: PTerrId ];
if(!lstUserterritory1.isEmpty()){
     RM = lstUserterritory1[0].UserId;
}

List<user> lstuser =[select email from user where id = :UserInfo.getUserId() ];
if(!lstuser.isEmpty()){
     UserEmail = lstuser[0].email;
}
```

Comment: Please help. I am unable to do the change.

Comment: @SFDC_Learner one min

Comment: @SFDC_Learner check my updated ans

Answer (score 1):

As **Stygon** and **highfive** said that the query is not returning any results.

The ideal approach world be to query a list first. Check the size of the list. If the size is greater than zero then use the data to get the Parentterritoryid. See [Salesforce Solution](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000159853&language=en_US)

Since you are trying to extract a `Parentterritoryid` directly from query and the where clause contains ID , Salesforce will try to retrieve only one SObject which if not found will lead to the error you are getting.

Try this:

```
List<territory> territoryList= [select Parentterritoryid,ID from territory where ID=: ParentTerr ];
if(territoryList!=null && !territoryList.isEmpty()){
     PterrId = territoryList.get(0).Parentterritoryid;
}
```

Comment: It worked but again same error here.  DM = [select UserId,territoryid from userterritory where territoryid =: ParentTerr ].UserId;

Comment: Please help. I am unable to do the change.

Comment: Please use the lists everywhere. That should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys! I got it!

```
get
        {   terrid = [select UserId, TerritoryID from Userterritory where UserID=: UserInfo.getUserId()].TerritoryID;
            ParentTerr = [select Parentterritoryid,ID from territory where ID=: terrid].Parentterritoryid;
            List<territory> territoryList= [select Parentterritoryid,ID from territory where ID=: ParentTerr ];
                if(territoryList!=null && !territoryList.isEmpty()){
                     PterrId = territoryList.get(0).Parentterritoryid;
                }

            List<userterritory> DMUser= [select UserId,territoryid from userterritory where territoryid =: ParentTerr];
              if(DMUser!=null && !DMUser.isEmpty()){
                     DM = DMUser.get(0).UserId;
                }
           // DM = [select UserId,territoryid from userterritory where territoryid =: ParentTerr ].UserId;
            if(PterrId!=null)
            RM = [select UserId,territoryid from userterritory where territoryid =: PTerrId ].UserId;


            UserEmail=[select email from user where id = :UserInfo.getUserId()].Email;

         //   UserTemp = [Select u.LastName, u.Id, u.FirstName, u.Email From User u limit 1];

            UserList = new List<SelectOption>();

            for(User temp : UserTemp)
            {
                UserList.add(new SelectOption(temp.Id, temp.Email));

            }
            return UserList;
        }
        set;
```